# Angular2 ngModel-var value does not same like this.var value

Tags: angular, input, ngmodel

I have some strange behavior by my ngModel-values within child-component.
html-code:

```
<input type="text" pattern="^[a-zA-Z]$"
                           class="form-control" required="true"
                           id="myId" 
                           [(ngModel)]="kName">
```

kName is an input field (@kName:string), which will be filled from parent-component.
I can see that  "this.kName" gets everytime new value from parent-component.
But when I set after some actions on this field on:

```
this.kName = undefined;
```

And then I want to fill kName again from parent, my kName-current value will not appear on html-output, but I can see on: this.kName
When I try to do like this:

```
<input type="text" pattern="^[a-zA-Z]$"
                           class="form-control" required="true"
                           id="myId" 
                           [(ngModel)]="{{this.kName}}">
```

I get error on `init` by html-pattern, because kName is undefined.
How can I refresh my ngModel-value? 
Maybe I have some other problems...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you have another problem anywhere..

Are there any error messages in you console?

Take a look at this plunker, works as expected: https://plnkr.co/edit/2VUOimDCMvPSNHD1mX69?p=preview

You can "clear" it and rewrite it from parent-component..

```js
import {Component, NgModule, Input} from '@angular/core'
import {FormsModule} from '@angular/forms'
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-child',
  template: `
    <input [(ngModel)]="kName" />
    <button (click)="clearFunction()">clear</button>
    <br />
    {{kName}}
  `,
})
export class Child {
  @Input() kName: string;

  constructor() { }

  clearFunction() {
    this.kName = undefined;
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2 (click)="changeSomething()">Hello {{name}}</h2>
      <my-child [kName]="myKname"></my-child>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name:string;
  myKname: string;

  constructor() {
    this.name = 'Angular2'
  }

  changeSomething() {
    this.myKname = Math.floor((1 + Math.random()) * 0x10000).toString(16).substring(1);
  }
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule, FormsModule ],
  declarations: [ App, Child ],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: Thx. for your example. Action in your Button "clear" is implemented withiin template. I have to do this within my child-component. Because of this i tried this.kName, cause kName within child-component ts-file could not be found.
How can i implement acton of this button:
`<button (click)="kName = undefined;">clear</button>`
within my ts.file?

Comment: Second problem is, when i implement button "clear" my html-pattern will failed. But it works at start?? kName is undefined too, but my html-pattern makes no troubles

Comment: You can do it in your ts-file as well, see updated answer and plunker.

Comment: Thx. you access to the variable "myKname" with this-operator. 
In my case "myKname" is declared like this:`
@input myKname:string`
 It works, but for some reason, it not works in one test-situation. Must be a bug, which i dont see just now^^

Comment: `myKname` is the property of that parent-component. So there it is no input, but in the child-component `kName` is the @Input(). Hope could help you or clarify some things.. gl ! :)